# Sonar for BizTalk

Tags: sonarqube, biztalk

Is there something in SONAR which can be used for BizTalk.  I used  BIZTALKCOP for Static Analysis using FxCop . But I am not sure how I can get this plugin with SONAR for BizTalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are currently no plans to support BizTalk.

Comment: Thanks for the information .. Is there a way i can force SONAR to read .btproj .. All the individual artifacts like schemas, maps etc are actually .Net there will be a CS file generated for these during build time .. so if i can force SONAR to scan these ..it will be good for me .. Thanks in advance...

Comment: SonarQube ignored generated code, and for a good reason: You cannot (or should not) edit those files! As soon as you start to edit generated files, it means you no longer can work with your original schemas/maps - making them useless. The good way would be directly analyze these schemas & maps, but there are no plans to do so for the time being.